# Angular 2 reloads page on POST request

Tags: angular

I am migrating an app from Angular 2 Beta 9 to Angular 2 RC5 and i experienced a huge amount of errors which i started eliminating and i got to the point where my console shows none.

However, when i submit a form to a rails server, the page just reloads and the console quickly shows an error but i cannot see it as its too fast

Anyway the code below worked just fine on the beta version, so any insight of what is going wrong here would be awesome (posting just the relevant part)

```
onSubmit() {

    this.myForm.value.systemParameters = this.system_arr;
    this.myForm.value.liftOperator = this.lift_arr;
    this.myForm.value.restrictOperator = this.restrict_arr;
    this.myForm.value.param = this.param_arr;
    this.myForm.value.xInitial = this.xinitial_arr;

    let myForm = JSON.stringify(this.myForm);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/webhook', myForm, { headers: headers }).subscribe(
      res => this.response = res.json(),
      error => console.log(error)
    );

    console.log('your submitted value:', this.myForm.value);
  }
```

Comment: wrap the error handler in brackets so you can stick a breakpoint in there and see what the error is

Comment: ah can you give an example?not sure i get it

Comment: replace `error => console.log(error)` with `error => { debugger; }`, and execution will pause on the debugger line. Or leave the `console.log` alone and just add a breakpoint in devtools. I assume you know how to use chrome devtools?

Comment: tried it now, still reloads page, i know how to use devtools in general, but i haven't used any breakpoints so i am not sure i know how to do that, i will find out i guess.

Comment: the reason it's reloading is not related to the code you posted. i'm just trying to help you catch the error

Comment: "i will find out i guess": I would *highly, highly, highly* recommend it. Devtools is your friend :-)

Comment: hehe yeah its high time i do that! cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but if the issue is the page reload after every POST request I would suggest to change the type of submit button to "button". This will prevent the page from reloading while sending the POST request to the server.

Like this guy suggests https://stackoverflow.com/a/33304509/4332884

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a button element with a type of submit. Remove the submit and change the button element to an anhor element. That should do the trick.

**Wrong:**

```
<form>
...
<button type="submit" (click)="letsDoThis()">Submit/button>
</form>
```

Right:

```
<form>
...
<a (click)="letsDoThis()">Submit</a>
</form>
```